# Swift How can I bring my Image after moving it back to the Middle ? Or rotate it back to the Origin position

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

I don't understand. how can I bring back my ImageView to the origin position (which is the Middle) of the view?

I want to use a TapGesture.

Or I have a second option to rotate it back to the original position. Currently I am trying to rotate it back but it doesn't work.

```
  @IBAction func backToOrigin(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let view = recognizer.view{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to undo a previous `CGAffineTransform` that you used to move or rotate your `view` you can use `view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity`. (Also, delete the use of `self` from your code because `self.view` and the `view` inside your `func` are different things.)

Comment: I will try it out

Comment: Thank you very much that was the answer